# How can I disable/falsify .remove() in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to falsify or disable `remove()` in an `if` statement. By default I have done this to a `div` called `#contentContainer`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contentContainer').remove();
});
```

Later on in my code I want to falsify/disable this. I have tried doing it like this:

```
if (this.id == "Product") {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#contentContainer').remove('#contentContainer', false);
    }, 1500);
}
```

I have also tried using:

```
$('#contentContainer').append();
```

But to no avail. Can someone help me understand and approach this properly?

Comment: Your question is not clear - what exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to be able to remove and element and then add it back again at a later time, I would suggest using `hide()` and `show()` instead of `remove()`.

Comment: If you want other people to understand you, then don't use terms, which in your opinion describe your question. Choose terms which really do. "Falsify" - what is it? How can falsify a statement?

Comment: to set remove(); to false when the if() becomes active?

Comment: @Nulle `if` condition has no such thing as being active. `remove` is a method, you cannot set it to false. You can either call it and remove a DOM element, or...not call it and not remove an element, obviously.

Comment: it might be obvious to you Yeldar because you know this. I dont. Once again thanks for any contributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, you want to `remove()` the element at a specific point in your code, then re-insert it back in to the DOM later on. If this is the case it would be much simpler to use `hide()` and `show()`. This way the element is always part of the DOM and you won't have to recreate it and any associated event handlers. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contentContainer').hide();
});

// later../
if (this.id == "Product") {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#contentContainer').show()
    }, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery remove function is actually removing the DOM element from the DOM itself, so u can't just 'disable' the remove operation (as u think u can).

for your purposes i guess u want to use the show/hide functions instead.

Comment: Thank you for making me understand this!